# How to use hover popup

Tags: html, css, hover

I have this code that has a hover effect on it. I have these four images in a row and all have this layer over them with a button and text. When you hover over the image the layer drops down. But what happens it once the mouse is not over the layer it goes back up and creates this weird glitch effect. I want it to stay down until you hover over it again.

Code:

```css
.card {
  position: relative;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 0;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  background-color: #fff;
  background-clip: border-box;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .125);
  border-radius: .25rem;
}

div.description {
  transition: height 500ms;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  z-index: 99;
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.7;
  overflow: hidden;
}

div.description:hover {
  background-color: #7d7d7d;
  height: 30%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container shadow" style="padding-top:35px;padding-bottom:35px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card"><img src="g_suite.png" class="card-img-top w-100 d-block" />
        <div class="description text-center">
          <a href="#gsuite">
            <br> <button type="submit">LEARN MORE</button>
          </a>
          <br><br>
          <h5>G Suite<br><br>and<br><br>Workflow Automation</h5>

          <p1>Communicate, Collaborate and get things done</p1>
          <br><br>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card"><img src="imageedit_1_4644664391.png" class="card-img-top w-100 d-block" />
        <div class="description text-center">
          <br>
          <a href="#website">
            <button type="submit">LEARN MORE</button>
          </a>
          <br><br>
          <h5>Website</h5>
          <br>
          <p1>Preserve Franchise Integrity with new <br>corporate design and quality standards.</p1>
          <br><br>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card"><img src="two-squares_icon-icons.com_55537.png" class="card-img-top w-100 d-block" />
        <div class="description text-center">
          <br>
          <a href="#zig_air">
            <button type="submit">LEARN MORE</button>
          </a>
          <br> <br>
          <h5>ZigAir</h5>
          <br>
          <p1>Preserve Franchise Integrity with new <br>corporate design and quality standards.</p1>
          <br><br>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="card"><img src="computer-phone-icon-78065.png" class="card-img-top w-100 d-block" />
        <div class="description text-center">
          <br>
          <a href="#it_assets">
            <button type="submit">LEARN MORE</button>
          </a>
          <br><br>
          <h5>IT Assets</h5>
          <br>
          <p1>IT products and management for you</p1>
          <br><br>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```